# TypeScript struggles with Redux containers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to properly type [Redux containers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components).

Consider a simple presentational component that might look like this:

```
interface MyProps {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
  onSelect: (name: string) => void;
}
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> { }
```

From the perspective of this component all props are required.

Now I want to write a container that pulls all these props out of state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState) {
  return {
    name: state.my.name,
    selected: state.my.selected
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch) {
  return {
    onSelect(name: string) {
      dispatch(mySelectAction(name));
    }
  };
}

const MyContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

This works, but there's a big typing problem: the mapping functions (`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`) have no protection that they are providing the right data to fulfill `MyProps`. This is prone to error, typos and poor refactoring.

I could make the mapping functions return type `MyProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState): MyProps { }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyProps { }
```

However this doesn't work unless I make all `MyProp` props optional, so that each mapping function can return only the portion they care about. I don't want to make the props optional, because they aren't optional to the presentational component.

Another option is to split up the props for each map function and combine them for the component props:

```
// MyComponent
interface MyStateProps {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

interface MyDispatchProps {
  onSelect: (name: string) => void;
}

type MyProps = MyStateProps & MyDispatchProps;

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> { }

// MyContainer
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState): MyStateProps { }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyDispatchProps { }
```

Ok, that's getting me closer to what I want, but its kind of noisy and its making me write my presentational component prop interface around the shape of a container, which I don't like.

And now a second problem arises. What if I want to put the container inside another component:

```
<MyContainer />
```

This gives compile errors that `name`, `selected`, and `onSelect` are all missing... but that's intentional because the container is connecting to Redux and providing those. So this pushes me back to making all component props optional, but I don't like that because they aren't really optional.

Things get worse when `MyContainer` has some of its own props that it wants to be passed in:

```
<MyContainer section="somethng" />
```

Now what I'm trying to do is have `section` a required prop of `MyContainer` but not a prop of `MyComponent`, and `name`, `selected`, and `onSelect` are required props of `MyComponent` but optional or not props at all of `MyContainer`. I'm totally at a loss how to express this.

Any guidence on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're on the right track with your last example. What you also need to define is a `MyOwnProps` interface, and type the `connect` function.

With these typings: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-redux/react-redux.d.ts, you can do something like this

```
interface MyProps {
  section: string;
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
  onSelect: (name: string) => void;
}

interface MyStateProps {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

interface MyDispatchProps {
  onSelect: (name: string) => void;
}

interface MyOwnProps {
  section: string;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> { }

function mapStateToProps(state: MyState): MyStateProps { }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyDispatchProps { }

const MyContainer = connect<MyStateProps, MyDispatchProps, MyOwnProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

This also lets you type `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, e.g.

```
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState, ownProps: MyOwnProps): MyStateProps
```

You don't need to define an intersection type for MyProps type as long as you define dispatch, state, and ownProps types. That way you can keep MyProps in its own place and let containers, or places where the component is used without containers, apply the props as they need to. I guess this is up to you and your use case - if you define `MyProps = MyStateProps & MyDispatchProps & MyOwnProps`, it's tied to one specific container, which is less flexible (but less verbose).

As a solution, it is pretty verbose, but I don't think there's any way of getting around telling TypeScript that the different pieces of required props will be assembled in different places, and `connect` will tie them together.

Also, for what it's worth, I have typically gone with optional props, for simplicity's sake, so I don't have much in the way of experience to share on using this approach.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I guess without TypeScript everything is optional anyway. I just like that component props can tell you what things are expected vs what things are optional.

Comment: Question: since this solution basically means you define each prop twice (once in `MyProps`, and once in the appropriate `MyStateProps` or `MyDispatchProps`), what happens if you rename or change a prop in `MyProps`, such as `name` to `id` or `selected: boolean` to `selected: SelectionEnum`? Does the type checker realize that `MyOwnProps, MyDispatchProps, MyStateProps` doesn't satisfy `MyProps` anymore?

Comment: Somewhat. I've been playing around with it since writing the answer. State and Dispatch props have to match, but OwnProps don't have to match. I guess maybe this is because it's possible to use ownProps only in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps and not use them in MyComponent?

Comment: The error is like `(123,3): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof FeatureTab' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<IStateToProps & IDispatchToProps> | StatelessComponent<IStateToProps & IDispatchTo...'`...

Comment: Ha, I don't think I'd know what that error is saying... does it trickle down to something helpful like `'name' exists in {...} but not in {...}`?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, since it is trying to match the properties of `FeatureTab` to the properties of `IStateToProps & IDispatchToProps`

Comment: Is there some shorthand that's happening here?

`function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyDispatchProps { }`

it seems like you are only declaring the signature of `mapDispatchToProps`, you still need to define what the function does right? So it should be:

`function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyDispatchProps {
    return {
        onAction: foo => dispatch(action(foo))
    };
}`?

If that's the case I find this awfully redundant since you define your state and dispatches twice

Comment: @PDN Yeah I didn't show the implementations of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` but it looks like that, and yes it all feels very redundant and awkward. Still haven't really found a balance between "easy to write" and "fully type checked" yet.

Comment: @Radio- Is this still a valid solution with TypeScript 2.9 and redux 4? I've been trying to apply it, but whenever I reference the connected component I get an error indicating I need to provide all properties (not just the ones specified in MyOwnProps).

Comment: Hi, can someone look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166259/typescript-ts2339-property-querytype-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattribu problem. I'm still facing this

Answer (score 3):

I just use `Partial<MyProps>`, where `Partial` is a built-in TypeScript type defined as:

```js
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
```

It takes an interface and makes every property in it optional.

Here's an example of a presentational/Redux-aware component pair I've written:

**/components/ConnectionPane/ConnectionPane.tsx**

```js
export interface IConnectionPaneProps {
  connecting: boolean;
  connected: boolean;
  onConnect: (hostname: string, port: number) => void;
}

interface IState {
  hostname: string;
  port?: number;
}

export default class ConnectionPane extends React.Component<IConnectionPaneProps, IState> {
   ...
}
```

**/containers/ConnectionPane/ConnectionPane.ts**

```js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {connectionSelectors as selectors} from '../../../state/ducks';
import {connect as connectToTestEcho} from '../../../state/ducks/connection';
import {ConnectionPane, IConnectionPaneProps} from '../../components';

function mapStateToProps (state): Partial<IConnectionPaneProps> {
  return {
    connecting: selectors.isConnecting(state),
    connected: selectors.isConnected(state)
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch): Partial<IConnectionPaneProps> {
  return {
    onConnect: (hostname, port) => dispatch(connectToTestEcho(hostname, port))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectionPane) as any;
```

The presentational component props are non-optional - exactly as required for the presentation without any bearing on the corresponding "smart" component.

Meanwhile, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` will allow me to assign a subset of the required presentational props in each function, while flagging any props not defined in the presentational props interface as an error.

Comment: Yeah, since the TS release with `Partial` support I've been using this on some projects. It's easy to use. It's not as strict as the formal `StateProps`, `DispatchProps` and `OwnProps` approach because it doesn't ensure a mapping function is complete, only that it doesn't return an incorrectly implemented prop. I've toyed with using `Pick` to pry apart a single presentational component props interface but that's still pretty tedious.

Comment: Making everything optional is not the solution as the question was asking clearly against it.

Comment: @wegginho OP wrote "However this doesn't work unless I make all **MyProp** props optional, so that each mapping function can return only the portion they care about. I don't want to make the props **[MyProp]** optional". My suggestion is *not* to make `MyProp` optional or indeed to make any change at all to the presentational component or its interface. It's to wrap `MyProp` in a type that exposes all of its properties as optional, only for the Redux typings. This is the ideal solution IMO as it allows each Redux function to handle a subset of props, while safeguarding against unknown props.

Comment: @Tagc is it complaining if you're not passing in required props?

Comment: @wegginho to which part, sorry? The presentational interface remains unchanged, so if you try to instantiate the presentational component directly, it will complain if you omit `name`, `selected` or `onSelect` (in the case of `MyProps`). For `mapStateToDispatch` and `mapStateToProps`, it will complain only if you return objects with unknown props (props that aren't `name`, `selected` or `onSelect`).

Comment: Wegginho is right that this isn't quite the *ideal* solution I was looking for because it does make all the props optional for the mapping functions, ie map functions aren't ensured to return everything they are supposed to. However it is quite a bit better than explicitly making the component props all optional and it is good alternative that's *easy* to use so I upvoted it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
interface MyStateProps {
    name: string;
    selected: boolean;
}

interface MyDispatchProps {
    onSelect: (name: string) => void;
}

interface MyOwnProps {
    section: string;
}

// Intersection Types
type MyProps = MyStateProps & MyDispatchProps & MyOwnProps;


class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> { }

function mapStateToProps(state: MyState): MyStateProps { }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDispatch): MyDispatchProps { }

const MyContainer = connect<MyStateProps, MyDispatchProps, MyOwnProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

You can use something use called **Intersection Types**
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types

Comment: Thanks for this example. It's basically a combination of my original attempt (using intersection types) and @radio's accepted answer (using the `connect()` type args).