# Typescript TS2339: Property 'queryType' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes' in Typescript + React + Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm using typescript in my react + redux application. One of my component make use of `react-redux`'s connect. The code is something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'redux'
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import {
  connect,
} from 'react-redux';

import withContextId from '../../../../../app/containers/pageTab/contexts/withContextId';

import {
  fetchContent,
} from '../../actions/workspaceActions';

import { HomePageQuery } from '../../interfaces';

interface Props extends StateProps, DispatchProps {
  queryType: string,
  query: string,
  contextId: string,
}

interface OwnProps {
  queryType: string,
  query: string,
  contextId: string,
}

class ContentContainer extends React.PureComponent<Props, {}> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { props } = this;

    props.fetchContent(props.queryType, props.query, props.contextId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {'Tiles Container'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

interface DispatchProps {
  fetchContent: (query: string, queryType: string, contextId: string) => void
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<any>): DispatchProps {
  return {
    fetchContent: (query: string, queryType: string, contextId: string) => {
      dispatch(fetchContent(query, queryType, contextId))
    }
  };
}

interface StateProps {
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any): StateProps {
  return {};
}

export default compose(
  withContextId,
  connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(ContentContainer);
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40681049/2648216) answer and tried separating my `StateProps`, `DispatchProps` and `OwnProps` but it'll still give me this error. How can I resolve this error?

**[EDIT]**
I'm receiving `queryType` and `query` from it's parent as (and these are mandatory props):

Comment: Where do you receive `qureyType` and `query` from?

Comment: I'm receiving `queryType` and `query` from it's parent

Comment: Have edited the question with ownProps and this component's usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue with the hoc `withContextId`. Apparently `withContextId` is written in JS and it doesn't have any typings.

Removing `compose` and doing below thing helped me solve the issue. A person with more `typescript` knowledge can get to it and make me understand as I'm still a newbie.

```
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(withContextId(ContentContainer));
```